# Windows "Symbol" or WGL4 font code point to UNICODE map?

Tags: windows, unicode, fonts, symbols

We use some OCR like PDF to Word converter which is the best we could find, but it uses the Symbol font table where for example, the degree symbol, appears as the code point U+F0B0, which is not a valid UNICODE point but it has a mapping to the proper UNICODE degree code point U+00B0. In fact all but one of the the Symbol font glyphs have a proper UNICODE character, but I am pulling my hair out not finding any table that would show a simple mapping.

This page http://www.alanwood.net/demos/symbol.html almost has it, but it doesn't actually show the Symbol font code points, but relies on some other mapping which, frankly, I don't understand at all. That same site has related pages but nowhere do I find F0B0 referenced for degree.

I found groff mappings of these special fonts to the old groff abbreviations, and it is the best I can get, there I can find in [symbol.map](https://opensource.apple.com/source/groff/groff-39/groff/font/devlj4/generate/symbol.map) a mapping of F0B0 to the abbreviation "de" and then I can find in [text.map](https://opensource.apple.com/source/groff/groff-39/groff/font/devlj4/generate/text.map) a mapping from 00B0 to "de". So if I was to reshape these two files to a relational table and then join on the abbreviation, I suppose I could create a mapping.

But I am stunned that nobody had to do that before? Anyone?

Comment: I do not know if somebody did it. On the other ways there is the "text shaping" libraries (a very complex topic, and we have one used by Windows, one by Mac, and two others). So in short: there is no way you can map a font glyph number (on a specific font) to one or more Unicode code points in a simple way. Probably you do not need to cover 100% of cases, so look the glyph and find the best unicode character, and build your "exception table".

Comment: A symbol-encoded font can support any arbitrary set of characters, including things not in Unicode. So, there isn't any defined mapping applicable to all symbol fonts. That's why you see Unicode private-use code points like U+F0B0 being used. At best, if a mapping is possible, it will be font-specific; and there's always a possibility that the glyphs in a font map to Unicode character sequences with complex m:n mappings.

Answer (score 1):

Ah well, I guess I didn't ask for a dissertation on the first principles of all possible symbolic fonts, no, I asked for whatever that Windows "Symbol" font is, that WGL4 code page or whatever I suppose "Monotype Symbol" font that is.

So here is what I did to generate the mapping from these groff font abbreviation maps I pointed to in my question:

```
wget https://opensource.apple.com/source/groff/groff-39/groff/font/devlj4/generate/symbol.map
sed -e '/^#/d' -e '/^ *$/d' -e 's/[\t ][\t ]*/|/g' symbol.map |cut -d\| -f2,3 |sort -t\| -k2 >symbol.map.dat
wget https://opensource.apple.com/source/groff/groff-39/groff/font/devlj4/generate/text.map
sed -e '/^#/d' -e '/^ *$/d' -e 's/[\t ][\t ]*/|/g' text.map |cut -d\| -f2,3 |sort -t\| -k2 >text.map.dat
wget https://opensource.apple.com/source/groff/groff-39/groff/font/devlj4/generate/special.map
sed -e '/^#/d' -e '/^ *$/d' -e 's/[\t ][\t ]*/|/g' special.map |cut -d\| -f2,3 |sort -t\| -k2 >special.map.dat
cat text.map.dat special.map.dat |sort -t\| -k2 > unicode.map.dat
join -t\| -1 2 -2 2 symbol.map.dat unicode.map.dat
```

Then I create an XML mapping table from that, which I use in my XSLT:

```
join -t\| -1 2 -2 2 symbol.map.dat unicode.map.dat |sed -e 's~\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)~<a abb="\1" sym="\&#x\2;" uni="\&#x\3;"/>~'
```

this creates:

```
<a abb="" sym="&#xF07C;" uni="&#x2243;"/>
<a abb="!" sym="&#xF021;" uni="&#x0021;"/>
<a abb="!=" sym="&#xF0B9;" uni="&#x2260;"/>
<a abb="#" sym="&#xF023;" uni="&#x0023;"/>
<a abb="%" sym="&#xF025;" uni="&#x0025;"/>
<a abb="&" sym="&#xF026;" uni="&#x0026;"/>
<a abb="(" sym="&#xF028;" uni="&#x0028;"/>
<a abb=")" sym="&#xF029;" uni="&#x0029;"/>
<a abb="**" sym="&#xF02A;" uni="&#x2217;"/>
<a abb="*A" sym="&#xF041;" uni="&#x0041;"/>
<a abb="*B" sym="&#xF042;" uni="&#x0042;"/>
<a abb="*C" sym="&#xF058;" uni="&#x039E;"/>
<a abb="*D" sym="&#xF044;" uni="&#x2206;"/>
<a abb="*E" sym="&#xF045;" uni="&#x0045;"/>
<a abb="*F" sym="&#xF046;" uni="&#x03A6;"/>
<a abb="*G" sym="&#xF047;" uni="&#x0393;"/>
<a abb="*H" sym="&#xF051;" uni="&#x0398;"/>
<a abb="*I" sym="&#xF049;" uni="&#x0049;"/>
<a abb="*K" sym="&#xF04B;" uni="&#x004B;"/>
<a abb="*L" sym="&#xF04C;" uni="&#x039B;"/>
<a abb="*M" sym="&#xF04D;" uni="&#x004D;"/>
<a abb="*N" sym="&#xF04E;" uni="&#x004E;"/>
<a abb="*O" sym="&#xF04F;" uni="&#x004F;"/>
<a abb="*P" sym="&#xF050;" uni="&#x03A0;"/>
<a abb="*Q" sym="&#xF059;" uni="&#x03A8;"/>
<a abb="*R" sym="&#xF052;" uni="&#x0050;"/>
<a abb="*S" sym="&#xF053;" uni="&#x03A3;"/>
<a abb="*T" sym="&#xF054;" uni="&#x0054;"/>
<a abb="*U" sym="&#xF055;" uni="&#x03A5;"/>
<a abb="*W" sym="&#xF057;" uni="&#x03A9;"/>
<a abb="*X" sym="&#xF043;" uni="&#x0058;"/>
<a abb="*Y" sym="&#xF048;" uni="&#x0048;"/>
<a abb="*Z" sym="&#xF05A;" uni="&#x005A;"/>
<a abb="*a" sym="&#xF061;" uni="&#x03B1;"/>
<a abb="*b" sym="&#xF062;" uni="&#x03B2;"/>
<a abb="*c" sym="&#xF078;" uni="&#x03BE;"/>
<a abb="*d" sym="&#xF064;" uni="&#x03B4;"/>
<a abb="*e" sym="&#xF065;" uni="&#xEFEC;"/>
<a abb="*f" sym="&#xF06A;" uni="&#x03C6;"/>
<a abb="*g" sym="&#xF067;" uni="&#x03B3;"/>
<a abb="*h" sym="&#xF071;" uni="&#x03B8;"/>
<a abb="*i" sym="&#xF069;" uni="&#x03B9;"/>
<a abb="*k" sym="&#xF06B;" uni="&#x03BA;"/>
<a abb="*l" sym="&#xF06C;" uni="&#x03BB;"/>
<a abb="*m" sym="&#xF06D;" uni="&#x03BC;"/>
<a abb="*n" sym="&#xF06E;" uni="&#x03BD;"/>
<a abb="*o" sym="&#xF06F;" uni="&#x03BF;"/>
<a abb="*p" sym="&#xF070;" uni="&#x03C0;"/>
<a abb="*q" sym="&#xF079;" uni="&#x03C8;"/>
<a abb="*r" sym="&#xF072;" uni="&#x03C1;"/>
<a abb="*s" sym="&#xF073;" uni="&#x03C3;"/>
<a abb="*t" sym="&#xF074;" uni="&#x03C4;"/>
<a abb="*u" sym="&#xF075;" uni="&#x03C5;"/>
<a abb="*w" sym="&#xF077;" uni="&#x03C9;"/>
<a abb="*x" sym="&#xF063;" uni="&#x03C7;"/>
<a abb="*y" sym="&#xF068;" uni="&#x03B7;"/>
<a abb="*z" sym="&#xF07A;" uni="&#x03B6;"/>
<a abb="+-" sym="&#xF0B1;" uni="&#x00B1;"/>
<a abb="+f" sym="&#xF066;" uni="&#x03D5;"/>
<a abb="+h" sym="&#xF04A;" uni="&#x03D1;"/>
<a abb="+p" sym="&#xF076;" uni="&#x03D6;"/>
<a abb="," sym="&#xF02C;" uni="&#x002C;"/>
<a abb="->" sym="&#xF0AE;" uni="&#x2192;"/>
<a abb="." sym="&#xF02E;" uni="&#x002E;"/>
<a abb="/" sym="&#xF02F;" uni="&#x002F;"/>
<a abb="/_" sym="&#xF0D0;" uni="&#x2220;"/>
<a abb="0" sym="&#xF030;" uni="&#x0030;"/>
<a abb="1" sym="&#xF031;" uni="&#x0031;"/>
<a abb="2" sym="&#xF032;" uni="&#x0032;"/>
<a abb="3" sym="&#xF033;" uni="&#x0033;"/>
<a abb="3d" sym="&#xF05C;" uni="&#x2234;"/>
<a abb="4" sym="&#xF034;" uni="&#x0034;"/>
<a abb="5" sym="&#xF035;" uni="&#x0035;"/>
<a abb="6" sym="&#xF036;" uni="&#x0036;"/>
<a abb="7" sym="&#xF037;" uni="&#x0037;"/>
<a abb="8" sym="&#xF038;" uni="&#x0038;"/>
<a abb="9" sym="&#xF039;" uni="&#x0039;"/>
<a abb=":" sym="&#xF03A;" uni="&#x003A;"/>
<a abb=";" sym="&#xF03B;" uni="&#x003B;"/>
<a abb="<" sym="&#xF03C;" uni="&#x003C;"/>
<a abb="<-" sym="&#xF0AC;" uni="&#x2190;"/>
<a abb="<=" sym="&#xF0A3;" uni="&#x2264;"/>
<a abb="<>" sym="&#xF0AB;" uni="&#x2194;"/>
<a abb="=" sym="&#xF03D;" uni="&#x003D;"/>
<a abb="==" sym="&#xF0BA;" uni="&#x2261;"/>
<a abb="=~" sym="&#xF040;" uni="&#x2245;"/>
<a abb=">" sym="&#xF03E;" uni="&#x003E;"/>
<a abb=">=" sym="&#xF0B3;" uni="&#x2265;"/>
<a abb="?" sym="&#xF03F;" uni="&#x003F;"/>
<a abb="AN" sym="&#xF0D9;" uni="&#x2227;"/>
<a abb="Ah" sym="&#xF0C0;" uni="&#x2135;"/>
<a abb="CL" sym="&#xF0A7;" uni="&#x2663;"/>
<a abb="CR" sym="&#xF0BF;" uni="&#x21B5;"/>
<a abb="DI" sym="&#xF0A8;" uni="&#x2666;"/>
<a abb="Eu" sym="&#xF0F0;" uni="&#x20AC;"/>
<a abb="HE" sym="&#xF0A9;" uni="&#x2665;"/>
<a abb="Im" sym="&#xF0C1;" uni="&#x2111;"/>
<a abb="OR" sym="&#xF0DA;" uni="&#x2228;"/>
<a abb="Re" sym="&#xF0C2;" uni="&#x211C;"/>
<a abb="SP" sym="&#xF0AA;" uni="&#x2660;"/>
<a abb="[" sym="&#xF05B;" uni="&#x005B;"/>
<a abb="]" sym="&#xF05D;" uni="&#x005D;"/>
<a abb="_" sym="&#xF05F;" uni="&#x005F;"/>
<a abb="ap" sym="&#xF07E;" uni="&#x007E;"/>
<a abb="arrowvertbt" sym="&#xF0DF;" uni="&#x21D3;"/>
<a abb="arrowverttp" sym="&#xF0DD;" uni="&#x21D1;"/>
<a abb="c*" sym="&#xF0C4;" uni="&#x2297;"/>
<a abb="c+" sym="&#xF0C5;" uni="&#x2295;"/>
<a abb="ca" sym="&#xF0C7;" uni="&#x2229;"/>
<a abb="cu" sym="&#xF0C8;" uni="&#x222A;"/>
<a abb="da" sym="&#xF0AF;" uni="&#x2193;"/>
<a abb="de" sym="&#xF0B0;" uni="&#x00B0;"/>
<a abb="di" sym="&#xF0B8;" uni="&#x00F7;"/>
<a abb="es" sym="&#xF0C6;" uni="&#x2205;"/>
<a abb="f/" sym="&#xF0A4;" uni="&#x2215;"/>
<a abb="fa" sym="&#xF022;" uni="&#x2200;"/>
<a abb="fm" sym="&#xF0A2;" uni="&#x2032;"/>
<a abb="gr" sym="&#xF0D1;" uni="&#x2207;"/>
<a abb="hA" sym="&#xF0DB;" uni="&#x21D4;"/>
<a abb="ib" sym="&#xF0CD;" uni="&#x2286;"/>
<a abb="if" sym="&#xF0A5;" uni="&#x221E;"/>
<a abb="integral" sym="&#xF0F2;" uni="&#x222B;"/>
<a abb="ip" sym="&#xF0CA;" uni="&#x2287;"/>
<a abb="lA" sym="&#xF0DC;" uni="&#x21D0;"/>
<a abb="la" sym="&#xF0E1;" uni="&#x2329;"/>
<a abb="lz" sym="&#xF0E0;" uni="&#x25C7;"/>
<a abb="mi" sym="&#xF02D;" uni="&#x2212;"/>
<a abb="mo" sym="&#xF0CE;" uni="&#x2208;"/>
<a abb="mu" sym="&#xF0B4;" uni="&#x00D7;"/>
<a abb="nb" sym="&#xF0CB;" uni="&#x2284;"/>
<a abb="nm" sym="&#xF0CF;" uni="&#x2209;"/>
<a abb="no" sym="&#xF0D8;" uni="&#x00AC;"/>
<a abb="pd" sym="&#xF0B6;" uni="&#x2202;"/>
<a abb="pl" sym="&#xF02B;" uni="&#x002B;"/>
<a abb="pp" sym="&#xF05E;" uni="&#x22A5;"/>
<a abb="product" sym="&#xF0D5;" uni="&#x220F;"/>
<a abb="pt" sym="&#xF0B5;" uni="&#x221D;"/>
<a abb="rA" sym="&#xF0DE;" uni="&#x21D2;"/>
<a abb="ra" sym="&#xF0F1;" uni="&#x232A;"/>
<a abb="sb" sym="&#xF0CC;" uni="&#x2282;"/>
<a abb="sd" sym="&#xF0B2;" uni="&#x2033;"/>
<a abb="sp" sym="&#xF0C9;" uni="&#x2283;"/>
<a abb="st" sym="&#xF027;" uni="&#x220D;"/>
<a abb="sum" sym="&#xF0E5;" uni="&#x2211;"/>
<a abb="te" sym="&#xF024;" uni="&#x2203;"/>
<a abb="ts" sym="&#xF056;" uni="&#x03C2;"/>
<a abb="u2026" sym="&#xF0BC;" uni="&#x2026;"/>
<a abb="u2320" sym="&#xF0F3;" uni="&#x2320;"/>
<a abb="u2321" sym="&#xF0F5;" uni="&#x2321;"/>
<a abb="ua" sym="&#xF0AD;" uni="&#x2191;"/>
<a abb="wp" sym="&#xF0C3;" uni="&#x2118;"/>
<a abb="~=" sym="&#xF0BB;" uni="&#x2248;"/>
```

or I can also create a lookup string of these invalid UNICODE points and a string of the position-matched proper UNICODE point:

```
join -t\| -1 2 -2 2 symbol.map.dat unicode.map.dat |sed -e 's~\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)~\1|\&#x\2;|\&#x\3;~' > symbol-unicode.map.dat
echo '<a sym="'$(cut -d\| -f2 symbol-unicode.map.dat |tr -d '\n')'" uni="'$(cut -d\| -f3 symbol-unicode.map.dat |tr -d '\n')'"/>'
```

which gives me:

```
<a sym="&#xF07C;&#xF021;&#xF0B9;&#xF023;&#xF025;&#xF026;&#xF028;&#xF029;&#xF02A;&#xF041;&#xF042;&#xF058;&#xF044;&#xF045;&#xF046;&#xF047;&#xF051;&#xF049;&#xF04B;&#xF04C;&#xF04D;&#xF04E;&#xF04F;&#xF050;&#xF059;&#xF052;&#xF053;&#xF054;&#xF055;&#xF057;&#xF043;&#xF048;&#xF05A;&#xF061;&#xF062;&#xF078;&#xF064;&#xF065;&#xF06A;&#xF067;&#xF071;&#xF069;&#xF06B;&#xF06C;&#xF06D;&#xF06E;&#xF06F;&#xF070;&#xF079;&#xF072;&#xF073;&#xF074;&#xF075;&#xF077;&#xF063;&#xF068;&#xF07A;&#xF0B1;&#xF066;&#xF04A;&#xF076;&#xF02C;&#xF0AE;&#xF02E;&#xF02F;&#xF0D0;&#xF030;&#xF031;&#xF032;&#xF033;&#xF05C;&#xF034;&#xF035;&#xF036;&#xF037;&#xF038;&#xF039;&#xF03A;&#xF03B;&#xF03C;&#xF0AC;&#xF0A3;&#xF0AB;&#xF03D;&#xF0BA;&#xF040;&#xF03E;&#xF0B3;&#xF03F;&#xF0D9;&#xF0C0;&#xF0A7;&#xF0BF;&#xF0A8;&#xF0F0;&#xF0A9;&#xF0C1;&#xF0DA;&#xF0C2;&#xF0AA;&#xF05B;&#xF05D;&#xF05F;&#xF07E;&#xF0DF;&#xF0DD;&#xF0C4;&#xF0C5;&#xF0C7;&#xF0C8;&#xF0AF;&#xF0B0;&#xF0B8;&#xF0C6;&#xF0A4;&#xF022;&#xF0A2;&#xF0D1;&#xF0DB;&#xF0CD;&#xF0A5;&#xF0F2;&#xF0CA;&#xF0DC;&#xF0E1;&#xF0E0;&#xF02D;&#xF0CE;&#xF0B4;&#xF0CB;&#xF0CF;&#xF0D8;&#xF0B6;&#xF02B;&#xF05E;&#xF0D5;&#xF0B5;&#xF0DE;&#xF0F1;&#xF0CC;&#xF0B2;&#xF0C9;&#xF027;&#xF0E5;&#xF024;&#xF056;&#xF0BC;&#xF0F3;&#xF0F5;&#xF0AD;&#xF0C3;&#xF0BB;" 
   uni="&#x2243;&#x0021;&#x2260;&#x0023;&#x0025;&#x0026;&#x0028;&#x0029;&#x2217;&#x0041;&#x0042;&#x039E;&#x2206;&#x0045;&#x03A6;&#x0393;&#x0398;&#x0049;&#x004B;&#x039B;&#x004D;&#x004E;&#x004F;&#x03A0;&#x03A8;&#x0050;&#x03A3;&#x0054;&#x03A5;&#x03A9;&#x0058;&#x0048;&#x005A;&#x03B1;&#x03B2;&#x03BE;&#x03B4;&#xEFEC;&#x03C6;&#x03B3;&#x03B8;&#x03B9;&#x03BA;&#x03BB;&#x03BC;&#x03BD;&#x03BF;&#x03C0;&#x03C8;&#x03C1;&#x03C3;&#x03C4;&#x03C5;&#x03C9;&#x03C7;&#x03B7;&#x03B6;&#x00B1;&#x03D5;&#x03D1;&#x03D6;&#x002C;&#x2192;&#x002E;&#x002F;&#x2220;&#x0030;&#x0031;&#x0032;&#x0033;&#x2234;&#x0034;&#x0035;&#x0036;&#x0037;&#x0038;&#x0039;&#x003A;&#x003B;&#x003C;&#x2190;&#x2264;&#x2194;&#x003D;&#x2261;&#x2245;&#x003E;&#x2265;&#x003F;&#x2227;&#x2135;&#x2663;&#x21B5;&#x2666;&#x20AC;&#x2665;&#x2111;&#x2228;&#x211C;&#x2660;&#x005B;&#x005D;&#x005F;&#x007E;&#x21D3;&#x21D1;&#x2297;&#x2295;&#x2229;&#x222A;&#x2193;&#x00B0;&#x00F7;&#x2205;&#x2215;&#x2200;&#x2032;&#x2207;&#x21D4;&#x2286;&#x221E;&#x222B;&#x2287;&#x21D0;&#x2329;&#x25C7;&#x2212;&#x2208;&#x00D7;&#x2284;&#x2209;&#x00AC;&#x2202;&#x002B;&#x22A5;&#x220F;&#x221D;&#x21D2;&#x232A;&#x2282;&#x2033;&#x2283;&#x220D;&#x2211;&#x2203;&#x03C2;&#x2026;&#x2320;&#x2321;&#x2191;&#x2118;&#x2248;">
```

By the way, there is a funny thing about the Stack Exchange platform that I can show you the symbols I have here, first the bad ones, which will probably show up all as boxes, unless you tweak your local CSS `style="font-family: 'Symbol';"`:



and now the UNIICODE string:

≃!≠#%&()∗ABΞ∆EΦΓΘIKΛMNOΠΨPΣTΥΩXHZαβξδφγθικλμνοπψρστυωχηζ±ϕϑϖ,→./∠0123∴456789:;<←≤↔=≡≅>≥?∧ℵ♣↵♦€♥ℑ∨ℜ♠[]_~⇓⇑⊗⊕∩∪↓°÷∅∕∀′∇⇔⊆∞∫⊇⇐〈◇−∈×⊄∉¬∂+⊥∏∝⇒〉⊂″⊃∍∑∃ς…⌠⌡↑℘≈

Pretty neat that.

[image]

Perhaps it can help someone else struggling with the same issue needing a quick practical solution. You're welcome.

Comment: And I will add a comment pointing out the errors in my result, apart from some XML well-formedness issues in the mapping elements due to the abb attribute values, we see the greek epsilon ε didn't come out, `&#xEFEC;` should have been `&#x03B5;`. The first character is also wrong, wonder if my pipe delimiter was causing that. But fair enough.